# Python TypeError: Tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple?

Tags: python

Trying to get a chunk of code working and one of my test cases is failing. It should be returning:

```
Invalid Point! (7, 8, 9, 10)
Invalid Point! ('hi', 2, 3)
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
```

Instead, I get the TypeError mentioned in the title and `Invalid Point! (1, 2, 3)`

Code below for reference.

```
def collection_check(a_coll, coll_template):
#Receives a collection to check and a template collection to check against.  The procedure
#raises errors if the collection to check is the incorrect type, is the wrong length, or 
#contains data types that do not match the data types of the provided template.
    if not type(a_coll)==type(coll_template):
        out_str = "TypeError:{} and template are different classes."
        raise TypeError(out_str.format(a_coll))
    if not(len(a_coll)==len(coll_template)):
        out_str = "ValueError:{} and template are different lengths." 
        raise ValueError(out_str.format(a_coll))
    for i in range(len(a_coll)):
        if not(type(a_coll[i])==type(coll_template[i])):
            out_str = "TypeError:{} is not type {}"
            raise TypeError(out_str.format(a_coll[i],type(coll_template[i])))

def clean_points(point_tup):
#Receives a tuple of tuples containing values and returns a new nested tuple with all 
#of the original tuples that contain exactly three numbers.
    new_points = []
    for point in point_tup:
        try:
            collection_check(point_tup[point],(0,0,0))
            new_points.append(point[:])
        except (TypeError,ValueError) as e:
            print("Invalid Point! {}".format(point))
            break
    return list(new_points)

###    
#Test cases:
#   >>> clean_points(((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9,10),('hi',2,3)))
#   Invalid Point! (7, 8, 9, 10)
#   Invalid Point! ('hi', 2, 3)
#   ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))
#   >>> clean_points((('h',0),(1,1,1),(2,2,2)))
#   Invalid Point! ('h', 0)
#   ((1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2))
###
```

What's going on? There are other issues in the code that I need to resolve, but this is the first roadblock I've found.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: It might help you to `print` each `point` during your `for point in point_tup:` loop, to see why you can't use it as an index as `[point]`

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with either of the test cases.

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `for point in point_tup:` to do? Specifically, what do you expect the value of `point` to be each time through the loop? Now check that assumption.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your code to print the error msg finally showed the error message you have mentioned in the title:

```
def collection_check(a_coll, coll_template):
#Receives a collection to check and a template collection to check against.  The procedure
#raises errors if the collection to check is the incorrect type, is the wrong length, or 
#contains data types that do not match the data types of the provided template.
    if not type(a_coll)==type(coll_template):
        out_str = "TypeError:{} and template are different classes."
        raise TypeError(out_str.format(a_coll))
    if not(len(a_coll)==len(coll_template)):
        out_str = "ValueError:{} and template are different lengths." 
        raise ValueError(out_str.format(a_coll))
    for i in range(len(a_coll)):
        if not(type(a_coll[i])==type(coll_template[i])):
            out_str = "TypeError:{} is not type {}"
            raise TypeError(out_str.format(a_coll[i],type(coll_template[i])))

def clean_points(point_tup):
#Receives a tuple of tuples containing values and returns a new nested tuple with all 
#of the original tuples that contain exactly three numbers.
    new_points = []
    for point in point_tup:
        try:
            collection_check(point_tup[point],(0,0,0))
            new_points.append(point[:])
        except (TypeError,ValueError) as e:
            print(e) # this will show the true error ========== right here 
            print("Invalid Point! {}".format(point))
            break
    return list(new_points)
```

You are trying to access a tuple of tuples with tuple, which does not make sense to python as you need to access the tuple of tuples with an integer index.
when looping like this

```
for point in point_tup:
```

the point variable contains the ith tuple in your `point_tup` variable, following your test case, point will equal in each iteration the following

```
(1, 2, 3)
(4, 5, 6)
(7, 8, 9, 10)
('hi', 2, 3)
```

so you do not need to get the point tuple like this

```
point_tup[point]
```

you already have it in `point` variable

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with these lines:

```
for point in point_tup:
    try:
        collection_check(point_tup[point],(0,0,0))
```

`point` is a tuple (assigned from iterating through `point_tup`, not an integer, so you can't use it to index into `point_tup`. Most likely you just want `collection_check(point, (0, 0, 0))`.